# Determining the correct size for a C++ array

Tags: c++

I need to be able to set the size of an array based on the number of bytes in a file.

For example, I want to do this:

```
// Obtain the file size.
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t file_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

// Create the buffer to hold the file contents.
    char buff[file_size];
```

However, I get a compile time error saying that the size of the buffer has to be a constant.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a vector.

```
std::vector<char> buff(file_size);
```

The entire vector is filled with '\0' first, automatically. But the performance "lost" might not be noticable. It's certainly safer and more comfortable. Then access it like a usual array. You may even pass the pointer to the data to legacy C functions

```
legacy(&buff[0]); // valid!
```

Comment: Yes, `std::vector` is the way to go. But I don't see why his code is failing in the first place. He is basically declaring a variable-length array, and I can't see anything illegal in that? It works when I try it in GCC.

Comment: It is legal C99, but not C++98.

Comment: @Hans: Variable-length array are a C99 feature. C++, however, is based on C89. So they aren't a C++ feature.

Comment: RaphaelISP and sbi: Thanks for clearing that up. I was uncertain as to whether variable length arrays had been included in C++. I also now note that GCC complains about this if invoked with `-pedantic`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) and not an array.

Real arrays require you to specify their size so that the compiler can create some space for them -- this is why the compiler complains when you don't supply a constant integer. Dynamic arrays are represented by a pointer to the base of the array -- and you have to retrieve the memory for the dynamic array yourself. You may then use the pointer with subscript notation. e.g.,

```
int * x;
x = (int *) malloc( sizeof(int) * 
                    getAmountOfArrayElements() /* non-const result*/ 
                  );
x[5] = 10;
```

This leads to two types of problems:

1. Buffer over/under flows : you might subscript-index past either end of the array.
2. You might forget to release the memory.

Vector provides a nice little interface to hide these problems from you -- if used correctly.

Comment: This is tagged `C++`. You should use `new`, not `malloc()`. But once you make all this exception-safe, you'd better off using `std::vector` anyway...

Comment: @Hassan: I wouldn't down-vote for a trivial reason, but I don't consider using `malloc()` in C++ programs trivial. That was advised against in the very first edition of _Effective C++_ by Scott Meyers in 1991 - I don't think the latest edition even mentions it, because it's such a well-known rule nowadays.

Comment: And what would you do when you want to allocate objects on thread local memory ? Try to shoehorn the feature into `new` ?

Comment: @Hassan: You would not use malloc either.

Comment: No but it wouldn't be `new` either. So what are we supposed to do then ? Not use a native API in favour of new ?

Comment: I think the point sbi is making is against `malloc`. In such a case, you wou probably use std::vector with a custom allocator...

Comment: What if this is for a multicore embedded device, and the company doesn't allow you to use the STL ? Would you still just stick to new ? Allocation is a concept, and you use what your coding conventions ask of you .... but to mark a perfectly valid response down because I chose to illustrate my reply using a c idom is just off.

Comment: Well, in such a situation, you know pretty much what you're doing and you don't have a choice anyway, so the usual "don't do this" rules don't apply :-)
But advocating for `malloc` for the general case is still a bit against the unwritten rules.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
char buff[file_size];
```

with

```
char *buff = new char[file_size];
```

and once the use of the buff is done..you can free the memory using:

```
delete[] buff;
```

Comment: No, don't. There's no good reason to use `new []` here instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: I'm down-voting because there is no mentioned of `vector`, sorry. Answer's shouldn't suggest raw memory handling when a standard type will do. It encourages bad programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are two points in your question I'd like to cover.

1. The actual question, how do you create the array.  Johannes answered this.  You use a std::vector and create it with a size allocation.
2. Your error message.  When you declare an array of some type, you must declare it with a constant size.  So for example

   const int FileSize = 1000;

   // stuff

   char buffer[FileSize];

is perfectly legitimate.

On the other hand, what you did, attempting to declare an array with variable size, and then not allocating with *new*, generates an error.

Answer (score -3):

Problem is that buff needs be created on the heap (instead of stack). Compiler want s to know the exact size to create on the stack.

```
char* buff = new char[file_size];
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `new[]` here instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: The question is setting the size of the array, not vector. I agree that vector is better but that's another issue. Whats the reason of the downvotes?

Comment: I downvoted because using new[] in this (or almost any) situation is simply not a good suggestion. Yes, the question uses the word "array" -- if he'd known enough to ask about "vector" instead, he wouldn't have needed to ask. It's clear that he wants is some data storage -- and equally clear that `new[]` isn't a good way to get that.